# A rigorous introduction to the convergence of Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I have been trying to find a resource on Fourier series and their convergence that is rigorous, does not leave major steps to the reader, and does not require a background in Lebesgue integration. Ideally this would be a set of computer verified formal proofs presented with accompanying text that could be read at an undergraduate level. Is there any chance that something like this might exist?

Comment: You might not want to hear this, but: why don't you first learn about Lebesgue integration?

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm not strictly opposed to it, and I have tried learning it in the past, but I seemed to get more sidetracked with it than I wanted to.

Comment: Riemann integral, I assume. How about the Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts If it requires the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, that is fine.

Comment: @Patrick : That helps because general Fourier series converge pointwise everywhere to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits for functions of bounded variation. And they converge uniformly on closed intervals contained in open intervals of continuity, for example. And bounded variation will get you the Spectral Theorem for unbounded selfadjoint operators as well. And you should be able to get the Central Limit Theorem, too. I'll see if I can find a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge and experience, the best exposition I ever found about the convergence of the Fourier series is that provided by Kolmogorov & Fomin in the relevant chapter of their [Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590054/) , among all the rest of the book that is definitely worthy to study carefully.

Their analysis starts from the [Dirichlet Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) and relevant integral, and goes through the Fejer's and Weierstrass theorems.

Answer (score 0):

An old classic that many people used is the Fourth Edition of *A Course of Modern Analysis* by E.T. Whittaker and G.N. Watson. Chapter IX is *Fourier Series and Trigonometrical Series*. They use only classical methods of analysis to study convergence